# Interpretation of local incidence angle map obtained from ENVI

Tags: geocoding, envi

[image: Local Incidence Angle map]

I obtained a Local Incidence Angle (LIA) map from ENVI while geocoding an ALOS satellite SLC image. It is said in the documentation of ENVI that the LIA map (in .tiff format) contains the angle at each pixel in degrees. When I read this .tiff in python, the values are in the range 0-255 and there are 3 bands.

How can I interpret this LIA map and obtain incidence angles in degree at each pixel location?

Comment: Can you share ENVI documentation link? Could be with a scale factor

Comment: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/pdf/sarscape_5.1_help.pdf This is the documentation I referred.

Comment: How big is extent of your scene? Is the incidence angle referred to geoid... If is big enough could have more sense... But I don't know why a 3 layer file is generated from this process... Maybe QA bands? Check .hdr file with a text editor, could be more information in this file

Comment: The actual size of scene is 8360 (samples) x 26105(lines) in SLC. When the image is geocoded , the size becomes 14516(rows)x12199(cols). The geoid referred is WGS84. The near range incidence angle is 25.3 degrees and far range incidence angle is 29.64 degrees. I exported _lia file as TIFF in ENVI

Comment: And the resolution of each pixel?

Comment: 6 meters is the pixel resolution.

Comment: That's weird for me... I have no answer for helping you